# How to get Python to ask for directory, read each filename in the dir and place that filename(without .csv) in the same file respectively?

Tags: python, csv

I'm very new to Python, I have several hundred folders with many thousands of files each containing times series data. Each file has an anonymized unique filename followed by an underscore and file number for each file (0 thru however many files are in the folder) "18667_0.csv, 18667_1.csv, 18667_3.csv" associated with it. I need to run a for loop that will take this unique filename "18667" and place it in whatever cell(Im using excel to read the csv) I choose for the same csv file. So if I have 300 files in the folder all will have the unique "18667" and I just want that number to be placed in the file. I have part of the code for the dir request but I've not been successful in combining the right read/write statements to implement this task. Here's what I have

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog
from os import listdir

def find_csv_filenames( path_to_dir, suffix=".csv" ):
    filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
    return [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( suffix ) ]

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
all_csvfiles = find_csv_filenames(folder_path, suffix= ".csv")

for filename in all_csvfiles:
    print(filename)
    a = filename
with open(a, 'w', newline="") as file:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(file) # 2. create a csvwriter object
    csvwriter.writerow(a)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Good that you enclose your (partial) code in tags. It would be easier to help you if you edit your question to exemplify what you wish outcome to be ? It's a little unclear from your description "place each filename in same file at cell A1 or A2" ?   Make a simplified example.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this is more clear.

Comment: You probably want to delete the last line and replace it with suitably indented `for filename in all_csvfiles:` and then `csvwriter.writerow(filename)`

Answer (score -1):

Wound up doing this.

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from os import listdir


# Listing all csv in folder
def find_csv_filenames(path_to_dir, suffix=".csv"):
    filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)  #returns all filenames
    return [filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(suffix)] 
#returns only csv filenames in a list []

#This is GUI for asking to select folder
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory() #Returns the folder you selected
all_csvfiles = find_csv_filenames(folder_path, suffix=".csv")  #lists filenames
print(folder_path)
for filename in all_csvfiles:  #begin loop thru all csv files
    print(filename)
    # a = filename
    InsertedName = filename[:-4]  #removes last 4 chars from filename
    print(InsertedName)
    tempfile = open(folder_path + "/temp.csv", "w") # creates a tempfile for 
writing(w) in the same dir
    tempfile.write(InsertedName+"\n")  #will write filename to temp and instruct 
for newline

    sourcefile = open(folder_path + "/" + filename, "r") #creates a sourcefile 
for reading original
    for line in sourcefile: #begins loop for writing original data to tempfile
        tempfile.write(line) #writes the data

    sourcefile.close()  #closes sourcefile
    Finalfile = open(folder_path + "/" + filename, "w")  #creating finalfile to 
overwrite existing file in dir
    tempfile.close()  #closes tempfile to return pointer to the top of file
    tempfile = open(folder_path + "/temp.csv", "r") #opens tempfile to write 
tempfile data to finalfile
    for line in tempfile: #loops the lines to write
        Finalfile.write(line)

    tempfile.close()
    Finalfile.close()
```